# angularjs routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am learning angularjs and created a demo application.

`Here is the` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ai3ta9e6NgUBQi5FW1SA?p=preview)

In that application I could not make the routing works properly.

When the "/main" route works perfectly but "/user/:username" did not work.

Can anyone please help me out to find the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `"teplateUrl"`. Changing it to `"templateUrl"` fixes your issue.

```
.when("/user/:username", {
    "controller": "UserController",
    "templateUrl": "user.html"
})
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VS9l3ftjwRInfDWdHsPh?p=preview).

Comment: ahh...that's ridiculous. Spent hours to figure out what's went wrong there. As I have little knowledge about angularjs, thought there must be something I am missing.
thanks a lot!